# SQL query breaks due to apostrophe

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I'm scraping data from third party sites using an html parser and then inserting the info that I need into MySQL. It just so happens that a lot of the info contains apostrophes in it. The trouble is that for the SQL query as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table (column) VALUE ('".$value."')
```

If the `$variable` has an apostrophe in it, the query breaks. There is simply too much info for me to manually insert it all. It would be entirely too time consuming. Any suggestions for me to make this query work?

Comment: What happens if the data has `'; drop table table --` in it?

Comment: `INSERT INTO table (column) VALUE ('" . mysql_real_escape_string( $value ) . "')` But better way use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead of `mysql`.

Comment: Where are the prepared statement answers?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic SQL injection flaw. If the value of `$value` is controlled by the user, they can basically do anything right now. The quote in the scraped string breaks out of the quoted environment within the SQL string, and thus allows for arbitrary SQL commands to be executed.

The short answer is, use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Of course, there's the obligatory "mysql_* is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO" part of this too.

Comment: Sorry. I'm a noob. But, what is PDO? I know about sql injections, but only wrap the value of something that is being used in a query in mysql_real_escape_string() when a user of my site is using my site. Obviously, I'm not going to do something harmful to my own DB.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php. Especially look at the `prepare` and `execute` sections. It allows you to build up a query with placeholders, then bind these to values when executing the query. Since they are done this way, SQL injection doesn't become an issue.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'll look into that. Does it increase execution time?

Comment: Erm, maybe? In any case, not significantly. If you're worried about execution time though, I have to ask why you're using PHP...

Comment: Ehhh. Not particularly concerned about execution time. Just wondering.

Comment: In any case, it won't have a significant performance impact. Test it ;)

Answer (score 1):

So in other words, your query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. Better use `PDO` or `MySQLi` Extension since you tagged `PHP.

Take time to read on this article: [**Best way to prevent SQL injection in PHP?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)